# Pandas use a date column to create a days columns with .shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time column set up as seen below:

```
   Times

   9/12/2014 5:02

   9/12/2014 5:03 

   9/12/2014 5:04 

   9/12/2014 5:05 

   9/12/2014 5:06 

   9/13/2014 5:07
   .

   .

   .

   9/12/2015 5:02
```

It goes from 2014 to 2015 and has a multitude of entries per day and within the year. I want to make a day column where when it sees 9/12/2014 = 1  9/12/2015 = 365 . How can I write this?

Im thinking roughly something along the lines of taking the difference between lines with a pandas.shift. Also something along the lines of spiting the date to only read in 12 from 9/12. So that if 12 - 12 = 0 day columns 1st entery = 1

Below is my rough thoughts.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('OOF',index_col=0,sep=",") 
j = 1
for i in len(time) 

if df['Diff'] = df['time'] - df['time'].shift(1) = 0

print j the day column 

else 
j =+1
print j the day column
```

I want this

```
   Times            days

   9/12/2014 5:02   1

   9/12/2014 5:03   1 

   9/12/2014 5:04   1 

   9/12/2014 5:05   1 

   9/12/2014 5:06   1 

   9/13/2014 5:07   2

   .                n

   .                n

   .                n

   9/12/2015 5:02   366
```

I never used dateframe or data conversions before. So maybe I am missing some information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datetime calculations

```
df['days'] = (df['Times'] - df['Times'].min()).dt.days + 1

                Times  days
0 2014-09-12 05:02:00     1
1 2014-09-12 05:03:00     1
2 2014-09-12 05:04:00     1
3 2014-09-12 05:05:00     1
4 2014-09-12 05:06:00     1
5 2014-09-13 05:07:00     2
9 2015-09-12 05:02:00   366
```

Comment: need to do pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format=True) with my data first but it works. Its so simple too! Thanks!